# I'm using the Unit of Work Pattern in my DAL, but I need to perform data access in Application_Start. What should I do?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, iis-7, httpcontext, unit-of-work

Given:

- When using the Unit Of Work pattern with an ORM in ASP.NET, the UnitOfWork object holds a reference to HttpContext.

Question:

- But what if I need to perform some data access in Application_Start ([especially in IIS7](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx))?
- Is the Unit Of Work pattern still viable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is your unit of work holding a reference to HttpContext?  To get at session state?  If this is the case, have it hold onto something more abstract (i.e. an interface), which in Application_Start will represent a concrete class that does not need HttpContext, and everywhere else will be another (that uses HttpContext internally)